# Comparing two paths in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

Consider:

```
path1 = "c:/fold1/fold2"
list_of_paths = ["c:\\fold1\\fold2","c:\\temp\\temp123"]

if path1 in list_of_paths:
    print "found"
```

I would like the if statement to return `True`, but it evaluates to `False`,
since it is a string comparison.

How to compare two paths irrespective of the forward or backward slashes they have? I'd prefer not to use the `replace` function to convert both strings to a common format.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use [`os.path.normpath`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to convert `c:/fold1/fold2` to `c:\fold1\fold2`:

```
>>> path1 = "c:/fold1/fold2"
>>> list_of_paths = ["c:\\fold1\\fold2","c:\\temp\\temp123"]
>>> os.path.normpath(path1)
'c:\\fold1\\fold2'
>>> os.path.normpath(path1) in list_of_paths
True
>>> os.path.normpath(path1) in (os.path.normpath(p) for p in list_of_paths)
True
```

- `os.path.normpath(path1) in map(os.path.normpath, list_of_paths)` also works, but it will build a list with entire path items even though there's match in the middle. (In Python 2.x)

On Windows, you **must** use [`os.path.normcase`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase) to compare paths because on Windows, paths are not case-sensitive.

Comment: And add os.path.normcase to convert to lowercase on windows - as windows should be case insensitive for comparisons.

Comment: But the OP says there may be any  of the slashes in any place

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, Thank you for  comment. I added a version that will handle such case.

Comment: list1 = ['a\\b\\c','x\y\z'],                               
list2 = ['a\\b','x\y'],

lis3 = [os.path.normpath(item) for item in list1 if os.path.isdir(item)],                                                            
list4 = [os.path.normpath(item) for item in list2 if os.path.isdir(item)]
                                                                            
for directory in list4:
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            if os.path.normpath(root) in list3:
  print "found"
 
but this code somehow fails !

Comment: @JagannathKs, It works for me (printing `found`) after slight modification (`lis3` -> `list3`, `x\y` -> `x\\y`, `x\y\z` -> `x\\y\\z`) and creation of the directorys `a\b\c`, `x\y\z`

Comment: There's still a gotcha on windows: 'c:\\users\\administrator\\foo.txt' is the same file as 'c:\\users\\admini~1\\foo.txt' thanks to the lameness that is 8.3 filenames.

Comment: I think you want to use `os.path.realpath`, to cover cases like @cbare mentions.

Comment: To add on @falsetru's answer, the nice thing about this solution is that it understands when you move to the parent folder, so `os.path.normpath("A\\B\\C\\..\\..\\test.txt") == "A\\test.txt"`.

Answer (score 25):

All of these answers mention `os.path.normpath`, but none of them mention [`os.path.realpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath):

> `os.path.realpath(path)`
>
> Return the canonical path of the specified filename, eliminating any symbolic links encountered in the path (if they are supported by the operating system).
>
> New in version 2.2.

So then:

```
if os.path.realpath(path1) in (os.path.realpath(p) for p in list_of_paths):
    # ...
```

Comment: Could you explain why this might be preferable to normpath?  Is the only difference symlinks?

Comment: I believe that is the only difference.

Answer (score 20):

The [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module contains several functions to normalize file paths so that equivalent paths normalize to the same string. You may want `normpath`, `normcase`, `abspath`, `samefile`, or some other tool.

Comment: +1 for `os.path.samefile(path1, path2)`. Using this removes the need to use `normpath()`, `realpath()`, or `normcase()` (on Windows OSes), before performing a string comparrison. However it requires both paths to exist on the filesystem or a `FileNotFoundError` exception will be raised and it does not resolve home relative paths, e.g. `~/Path/To/File`, for these use `expanduser()`. Note: Python 3.2 added `samefile()` support for Windows OSes.

Comment: +1 also for samefile and just to mention: despite the name "samefile" also allows for checking directories! see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 9):

If you are using [python-3](/questions/tagged/python-3), you can use [pathlib](/questions/tagged/pathlib) to achieve your goal:

```
import pathlib
path1 = pathlib.Path("c:/fold1/fold2")
list_of_paths = [pathlib.Path(path) for path in ["c:\\fold1\\fold2","c:\\temp\\temp123"]]
assert path1 in list_of_paths
```

Comment: I like this answer but I would like to add that you can also use relative paths such as follows: `Path('..').resolve() in [Path('.').resolve().parent]`, which is mostly `True` except when there is no more parent.

Answer (score 2):

Store the list_of_paths as a list instead of a string:

```
list_of_paths = [["c:","fold1","fold2"],["c","temp","temp123"]]
```

Then split given path by '/' or '\' (whichever is present) and then use the `in` keyword.

Comment: Hi Ashwin, I am not sure which variable has what slash as both are generated dynamically  and i cannot replace every string as i would be surfing large data

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.path.normpath` to canonicalize the paths before comparing them. For example:

```
if any(os.path.normpath(path1) == os.path.normpath(p)
       for p in list_of_paths):
    print "found"
```

Comment: os.path.normpath is for normalizing the paths, we should use os.path.realpath for canonicalizing.

Comment: @baky That depends on the exact requirements. Since the OP requested comparison "irrespective of forward or backward slash", which `normpath` fulfills. It is of course possible that the OP misstated their requirements two and a half years ago, but that would be guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `os.path.samefile(path1, path2)`.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.samefile